# Unexpected values in an allocatable array of derived types

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90

I want to assign initial values to an allocatable array of structures.
The structure in a module is like this:

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = 8
TYPE :: Message
  INTEGER :: l
  INTEGER :: species
  INTEGER :: molecule
  REAL(KIND=dp) :: vxx
  REAL(KIND=dp) :: vyy
  REAL(KIND=dp) :: vzz
END TYPE Message
TYPE(Message), ALLOCATABLE :: products(:)
```

In the main function I allocate the array and initialize it like:

```
  ALLOCATE (products(sizeofpro))
  DO i =1, sizeofpro
    products(i)%l = 1
    products(i)%species = 0
    products(i)%molecule = 0
    products(i)%vxx = 0.0_dp
    products(i)%vyy = 0.0_dp
    products(i)%vzz = 0.0_dp
  END DO
```

When I use `gdb` to debug it by typing `p products(1)`, it shows:

```
$1 = (0, 0, 0, 1.3888616748813736e-269, 4.9782021256040348e-311, 2.121995791459338e-314)
```

and the initialization doesn't work.

I run this code in parallel with MPI and compile code with mpif90.

Any ides why this happens?

Comment: What is the output if you print the values after the initialization loop from within the program?

Comment: @IRO-bot The output doesn't change, it shows same values shown above.

Comment: In any case, your `products(1)` appears uninitialized in the output. I  cannot reproduce your problem with either gfortran, ifort nor pgf90. Somebody else might have an idea. It would be useful if you add the compiler name, version, and flags in your question.

Comment: @IRO-bot thanks anyway. I wrote a small program to reproduce this problem, but it works well in the small program. However, when I add the same code into a project, the problem jumps out.

Comment: @IRO-bot If I use print to print the array, the output is right. So I think it's a problem caused by gdb.

Comment: There you go, this is why I asked what is the output from the program in the first place.

Comment: @IRO-bot Do you know why I can't print it out on dbg?

Comment: No, but my guess is that you did not run the init loop in gdb before printing the values.